# What does error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘float’ and ‘int’) mean

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float with;
    float inacbal;
    float acleft;
    scanf("%f",&with);
    scanf("%f",&inacbal);
    if((with%5)==0)//error here
    {
        acleft=inacbal-with-0.50;
        printf("%f",acleft);
    }
    else
        printf("%f",inacbal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It means you can't do a modulo of a float by an int.

Comment: Please format code as code, not as a quotation.

Comment: `%` is an integer operator. `with` is a `float`.

Comment: The C standard 6.5.5: "The operands of the % operator shall have integer type." Your program does not conform to the C standard, so you get a compiler error.

Comment: It simply means that you cannot have a float as an operand for the 
 %(mod) operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float with;
if((with%5) == 0)
```

is incorrect. You can apply `%` only to integers. If you really want to do a modulo operation on `float`, then use [fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) or if you're not bothered about the sign of the remainder, then use the new IEEE 754r mandated C99's [remainder](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remainder).  From Sun's [Numerical Computation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_lib.html):

> The remainder(x,y) is the operation specified in IEEE Standard 754-1985. The difference between remainder(x,y) and fmod(x,y) is that the sign of the result returned by remainder(x,y) might not agree with the sign of either x or y, whereas fmod(x,y) always returns a result whose sign agrees with x.

Comment: Then how I an check the remainder of it

Comment: @Dumb does `with` have to be a float? Can it be an `int`? If it needs to be a float, then look at `fmod`.

Comment: +1 `with` can be an integer and the whole problem would go away.

Comment: Actually in order to avoid typecasting in this line acleft=inacbal-with-0.50;.I am putting all variables in float otherwise there will be some precision error

Comment: Use the right data types that makes sense for what quantity the variable denotes; then type case only when you need to. Say you could do `acleft = inacbal - (float) with - 0.5f;`.

Comment: @Dumb Making `with` a `float` instead of an `int` if it really is integer does not help with precision in the `aclef = inacbal - with - 0.50` calculation. A certain amount of precision error will occur with `float` regardless.

Comment: If I"LL just put float acleft and other in integers then won't there be any precision loss?

Comment: If you're measuring quantities which can be only integers (discrete) then use `int` e.g. would be number of _people_, _keys on a keyboard_, _columns on a terminal window_, _files on a machine_, etc. If you want to measure quantities that can be fractions (continuous) then use `float` (or `double` depending upon the precision you want) e.g. _volume_, _length_, _money_, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because you can't use the modulus operator (`%`) with `float`.

If you want to calculate the remainder of it,use `fmod()` like this:

```
fmod(with,5);
```

`fmod` will return the remainder of the division. Don't forget to include `math.h` in order to use `fmod`.